# Estimating a logistic mixed model with highly dependent random effects

Tags: regression, logistic, mixed-model, singular-matrix

I want to estimate a logistic mixed model with two crossed random intercepts, (let's call the variables A and B) with the lme4 package. 
Unfortunately, I get the warning that my model is singular and the variance of A is estimated to be 0.
However, when I only include the variable A without B the variance is around 0.8. Do you have any ideas how to address this issue?

Comment: Please post a link to your data